# How to capture the screens on recording and playback using Jmeter?

Tags: jmeter

Currently, i am recording and playback my test plan in Jmeter? Which is working fine?And now, i needs to capture the screen of the web page while recording and playback my test plan. Any possibilities in Jmeter or any other plugins to configure, please let me know.

Answer (score 2):

JMeter on it's own does not and will not have any screen capture capabilities.
It **might** be possible with the JMeter webdriver plugin:

[Take a screenshot with Selenium WebDriver](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3422262/take-a-screenshot-with-selenium-webdriver)
http://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/WebDriverTutorial/
http://blazemeter.com/blog/jmeter-webdriver-sampler